# Determine if an ideal is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm trying to determine if $(7)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ so what I did was:

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/ (7) \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/(x^2+5,7) \cong \mathbb{F}_7[X]/(x^2+5) \cong \mathbb{F}_7[X]/(x^2-2) $

Now I'm pretty sure that $x^2+5$ and $x^2-2$ and prime in this field, so the quotient field is an integral domain. So then $(7)$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. But I read somewhere that $(7)$ is not a prime ideal so I don't know where I went wrong? Am I wrong to say that the polynomial $x^2+5$ or $x^2-2$ is prime?

Comment: it is clearly not prime! $9-2=7$

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: $x^2-2$ has two root in $F_7$:$3,-3$

Comment: oh wait yes, (x-3)(x+3)... oh man ok! that was a dumb moment! I don't know why i didnt think of that!

Comment: $2=3^2$ in $\mathbb F_7$, so $x^2-2=(x+3)(x-3)$.

Comment: So tracing back to the original problem, $(3 + \sqrt{-5}) (3 - \sqrt{-5}) =14 \in (7)$ but neither $3 + \sqrt{-5}$ nor $3 - \sqrt{-5}$ is in $(7)$.